How to correctly configure config.toml in Ballerina for MySQL connection?
I am working on a Ballerina project and need to connect to a MySQL database. I'm using config.toml to store my MySQL connection details, but I'm unsure of the correct format and fields required.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far in config.toml:
host = "localhost"
port = 3306
username = "root"
password = "password"
database = "testdb"

In my Ballerina service, I am loading these configurations to initialize the MySQL client, but I keep encountering errors such as Invalid database configuration or Connection timeout.
Could someone guide me on the correct way to configure the config.toml file for a MySQL connection in Ballerina, and how to use these configurations in the Ballerina code to establish a successful connection?
Here is my db.bal. I tried these approaches and getting the mentioned error Error Message
import ballerinax/mysql;
import ballerina/sql;
// import ballerinax/mysql.driver as _;

// Configurable variables
configurable string HOST = ?;
configurable int PORT = ?;
configurable string USERNAME = ?;
configurable string PASSWORD = ?;
configurable string DATABASE = ?;

// Client options configuration (if needed)
configurable mysql:Options & readonly connectionOptions = {};

// Initialize the MySQL client
mysql:Client|sql:Error dbClientResult = new (HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);

// Ensure dbClient is correctly initialized
 final mysql:Client dbClient = check dbClientResult;

# Insert a new user into the database
isolated function insertUser(User entry) returns sql:ExecutionResult|error {
    User {userId, email, password, createdAt, updatedAt} = entry;
    sql:ParameterizedQuery insertQuery = `INSERT INTO users (id, email, password, createdAt, updatedAt) 
                                          VALUES (${userId}, ${email}, ${password}, ${createdAt}, ${updatedAt})`;
    return dbClient->execute(insertQuery);
}

# Select a user by ID
isolated function selectUserById(int id) returns User|sql:Error {
    sql:ParameterizedQuery selectQuery = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ${id}`;
    return dbClient->queryRow(selectQuery);
}

# Select a user by email (for login)
isolated function selectUserByEmail(string email) returns User|sql:Error {
    sql:ParameterizedQuery selectQuery = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ${email}`;
    return dbClient->queryRow(selectQuery);
}

# Insert a new chat into the database
isolated function insertChat(Chat entry) returns sql:ExecutionResult|error {
    Chat {chatId, userId, role, text, img, createdAt} = entry;
    sql:ParameterizedQuery insertQuery = `INSERT INTO chats (id, userId, role, text, img, createdAt) 
                                          VALUES (${chatId}, ${userId}, ${role}, ${text}, ${img}, ${createdAt})`;
    return dbClient->execute(insertQuery);
}

# Select a chat by ID and userId
isolated function selectChatByIdAndUser(int id, int userId) returns Chat|sql:Error {
    sql:ParameterizedQuery selectQuery = `SELECT * FROM chats WHERE id = ${id} AND userId = ${userId}`;
    return dbClient->queryRow(selectQuery);
}

# Select all chats for a user
isolated function selectChatsByUserId(int userId) returns Chat[]|error {
    sql:ParameterizedQuery selectQuery = `SELECT * FROM chats WHERE userId = ${userId}`;
    stream<Chat, error?> chatStream = dbClient->query(selectQuery);
    return from Chat chat in chatStream select chat;
}

# Insert a new user chat entry into the database
isolated function insertUserChat(UserChat entry) returns sql:ExecutionResult|error {
    UserChat {id, userId, chatId, title, createdAt} = entry;
    sql:ParameterizedQuery insertQuery = `INSERT INTO user_chats (id, userId, chatId, title, createdAt) 
                                          VALUES (${id}, ${userId}, ${chatId}, ${title}, ${createdAt})`;
    return dbClient->execute(insertQuery);
}

# Select all user chats by userId
isolated function selectUserChatsByUserId(int userId) returns UserChat[]|error {
    sql:ParameterizedQuery selectQuery = `SELECT * FROM user_chats WHERE userId = ${userId}`;
    stream<UserChat, error?> userChatStream = dbClient->query(selectQuery);
    return from UserChat userChat in userChatStream select userChat;
}

I am using:

Ballerina version: 2201.10.0 (Swan Lake Update 10)

Any help or working examples would be appreciated!

Please don't post exact duplicates of another question that's in the Staging Ground.

There are a couple of issues in your code.

You need the mysql.driver import since you cannot connect to the MySQL database without the driver.
Your configuration variables and the values in the Config.bal are different. These are case-sensitive and you should follow that. Using this Config.toml would fix this:
HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 3306
USERNAME = "root"
PASSWORD = "password"
DATABASE = "testdb"



You can check this guide to learn more about the Ballerina configurations.

I already did that but still showing those errors

In the screenshot you shared originally, it seems like there are some warnings related to parsing the TOML content. Can you try resolving them first to ensure the TOML content is correct and then try running the program?

@AdithyaBandara Can you show what errors you get after fixing these?

i got it thanks for your support

Make sure that you have a MySQL db running locally.

mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p
Enter the pass
Execute USE testdb;

